# Resetting a Bacon property on value changed to empty

Tags: bacon.js

**TL;DR**

How can I reset `emailProfile`/`aliasProfile` when `email`/`alias` is cleared after having a value?

**Slightly longer version**

I have a form that has inputs for `email` and `alias`. Neither is mandatory. But, if you fill in the `alias` field, it might require the `email` as well, if the `alias` is reserved.

So far so good, I have the pipe setup from an empty form, up until checking if an `alias` is reserved and whether the given `email` matches up. This works correctly and reliably.

Where my setup falters, is when after filling in a correct e-mail I clear the `email`. The status of `emailProfile` remains status quo (last server response).

What I want to achieve, is to clear `emailProfile` when `email` has no value (or actually when `validEmail` is false), but in all other cases return the last server response.

The direct (and only) way to tackle the problem I can think of, would be to drop the `filter` and return `null` from the lookup function when validation fails, but there has to be a better way, right?

```
// Functions that can be assumed to work as they should (they do):
// form.findInput, validAlias,validEmail, compose, 
// fetchProfilesByAlias, fetchProfileByEmail

var alias = Bacon.fromEventTarget(form.findInput("alias"), "change").
    merge(
        Bacon.fromEventTarget(form.findInput("alias"), "keyup")
    ).
    map(".target").
    map(".value").
    skipDuplicates().
    toProperty(form.findInput("alias").value);

var email = Bacon.fromEventTarget(form.findInput("email"), "change").
    merge(
        Bacon.fromEventTarget(form.findInput("email"), "keyup")
    ).
    map(".target").
    map(".value").
    skipDuplicates().
    toProperty(form.findInput("email").value);

var aliasProfiles = alias.
    debounce(600).
    filter(validAlias).
    flatMapLatest(compose(Bacon.fromPromise.bind(Bacon), fetchProfilesByAlias)).
    toProperty(null);

var emailProfile = email.
    debounce(600).
    filter(validEmail).
    flatMapLatest(compose(Bacon.fromPromise.bind(Bacon), fetchProfileByEmail)).
    toProperty(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most straightforward way I can think of.

```
var emailProfile = email.
  debounce(600).
  flatMapLatest(function(email) {
    if (validEmail(email)) {
      return Bacon.fromPromise(fetchProfileByEmail(email))
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }).
  toProperty(null)
```

Pretty much the same that you already discovered, except the `if` is not in the lookup function :)

Comment: Thanks. This is essentially what I did, with some minor, mostly cosmetic differences in the implementation. Maybe I'm not so clueless as I thought I am. I'm very new to Bacon.js, but it smells delicious.